# Sitecore Access Denied Error on Browsing Datasource to associate content Page Editor

Tags: sitecore

I see the below error message in the logs when I click on Browse Datasource when trying to associate content with a control.

Exception: Sitecore.Exceptions.AccessDeniedException 
Message: Access denied 
Source: Sitecore.Kernel 
at Sitecore.Web.UI.XamlSharp.Xaml.XamlPageHandlerFactory.CheckAccess(ControlUri uri) 
at Sitecore.Web.UI.XamlSharp.Xaml.XamlPageHandlerFactory.GetXamlPageHandler(HttpContext context, String appRelativeVirtualPath) 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: If you don't post the code, people can only guess.

Comment: Its a sitecore specific error, no custom code involved

Answer (score 1):

I think the important part of the stack trace is the `CheckAccess` method. Examining the Sitecore code (`XamlPageHandlerFactory` class), I can see that the error is only thrown if the following criteria are met:

- The requested page is not excluded from access checks.
- The site is "shell"
- The user is not authenticated

The only pages excluded from access checks are:

- Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Analytics.VisitorIdentification
- Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Analytics.Subscription

so as expected, your page definitely isn't excluded.

Since you are browsing for a datasource, I assume that the context site must be "shell".

So all that remains is that the authentication point. Could it be that your session expired before you opened the window, or that you were logged out for some other reason?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response, I looked at the above variables too.. I am able to browse through the other content as part of the session, look at security/access manager etc . I dont think its a time out.. Does Context.User.IsAuthenticated check for roles ? I am wondering if there needs to be permissions defined on the data source in core?

Comment: I don't think `IsAuthenticated` checks roles. it's the standard .net property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.isauthenticated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx